# Permutations with Repetition Symbol

Tags: summation, combinatorics, permutation

I am trying to compute this formula in Mathematica:

$$ a = \sum_{n=0}^A P_A^{A-n,n}  $$

Where A can be any positive number

The problem is that I am unable to find the symbol for permutations with repetition:

$$ P_n^{n_1,n_2,...,n_m}   $$

Note:
I know that the result is going to be:

$$ a = \sum_{n=0}^A P_A^{A-n,n} = 2^A  $$

But I would like to compute it with the "Permutations with Repetition Symbol"

Comment: Can you give a reference for this formula?

Comment: Here it is: https://www.emathematics.net/combinaprepeticion.php?a=7

Comment: Ah, then as I noted in Marco's answer, that's just the [multinomial coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's define a function that calculates the number of permutations with repetitions, according to [this definition](https://www.superprof.co.uk/resources/academic/maths/probability/combinatorics/permutations-with-repetition.html):

$$Pr^{\ a,\,b,\,c,\,...}_{\ n}=\frac{n!}{a!\ b!\ c!\ ...}\ \ \ \ \ \ n=a+b+c+\ ...$$

```
Clear[pr]
pr[a__] := Plus[a]! / Times@@ ({a}!)
```

Then let's see if your sum evaluates symbolically:

```
Sum[pr[a - n, n], {n, 0, a}]
(* Out: 2^a*)
```

Look at that! It works!

---

A more direct route is built in, [as @JM mentioned in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221682/permutations-with-repetition-symbol/221688?noredirect=1#comment564311_221682). The number of permutations with repetitions corresponds to the [multinomial coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html), which is implemented in Mathematica as the [`Multinomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multinomial.html) function:

```
Multinomial[2, 3, 4] == pr[2, 3, 4]    (* True *)
```

When called with two non-numerical arguments, `Multinomial` is evaluated to an equivalent `Binomial` call:

```
Multinomial[a, b]                      (* Out: Binomial[a + b, b] *)
```

With more than two non-numerical arguments it returns unevaluated (whereas `pr[a, b, c]` returns the definition, i.e. `(a + b + c)! / (a! b! c!)`).

In your case, @JM showed that your result can be obtained as follows:

```
Sum[Multinomial[a - n, n], {n, 0, a}]  (* Out: 2^a *)
```

Comment: I was hoping the OP would supply the definition, but since you have already done so: `Sum[Multinomial[a - n, n], {n, 0, a}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. That's certainly much tidier :-)

Comment: So, should I accept MarcoB's answer, or the one of J.M.'s? I think both are great

Comment: @Die If Marco edits his answer to include my observation, then accept his answer.

Comment: @DieDauphin I've added J.M.'s `Multinomial` approach to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For fun (*only*):

```
☺ = 1 ## &[(+##)!, 1 ## & @@ ({##}!)^-1] &;

☺[a, b, c]
```

[image]

Comment: This is *so* readable to a non-*Mathematica* user! (But it is fun! :)

Comment: Hehe. I had to copy it into MMA and unravel it. The 1's got me :-)